# How to simulate the process of login using scrapy, when the information might be tranferred by ajax?

Tags: python, ajax, scrapy

I'm doing some crawling jobs on http://www.asianmetal.cn/.
But I fail to login using a simple FormRequest like this:

```
def start_requests(self):
    url = 'http://www.asianmetal.cn/login/ajaxLogin.am'
    fake_header = httputils.random_headers()
    formdata = {
        'txtUser_LoginName': '***',
        'txtUser_Pwd': '***',
        'tfc': '1',
    }
    yield scrapy.FormRequest(url=url, formdata=formdata,
        headers=fake_header, callback=self.parse)
```

However it doesn't work. So I did screenshots to find out what happened.

[image: Formdata]

So how should I simulate the login process?

Comment: You have `'tfc': '1',` in your code but your screenshot shows `ifc`. Maybe that's the cause?

Comment: sorry. I changed to ifc but it still didn't work...

Comment: You are missing the query param which is the iso date string

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing some headers. I've tried gibberish log in and these are the headers that were sent:

[image]

The only important here is probably `X-Requested-With`. Some websites also check `Referer` but that's really rare.

To fix this simply update your fake header with approriate values:

```
fake_header = {}
fake_header['X-Request-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest'
fake_header['Referer'] = response.url
```

Comment: Thanks. I update the `fake_header` as you told me. But it still doesn't work. (btw, I check the login state by using `scrapy` function `open_in_browser`)

Comment: @Kadakyo I can't really test this, but maybe you could provide crawl logs and the entirity of what your `fake_header` ends up being?

Comment: `fake_header` is like this `{'Connection': 'keep-alive',
 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR': '186.16.132.36',
 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0',
 'http_client_ip': '186.16.132.36'}` ip numbers are combined with random numbers.

Comment: @Kadakyo have you tried setting `fake_header` to an empty dictionary? i.e. `fake_header = {}`. Can you log in then?